# 2048 game in Python 3

Tags: python, game, pygame, 2048

I wrote this 2048 game using Python 3 and pygame a few weeks ago. Since I'm getting into CS this summer, I would like to get some review on how I can improve my code in generel. Any tips and improvements are welcome, and highly appreciated.

The code is found below:

```py
import pygame
import random

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # SETUP pygame environment
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
        pygame.display.set_caption('2048')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # Create the Board
        self.board = Board()
        #self.board.add_tile()
        self.run()

    def paint(self):
        # Paint the background
        self.screen.fill((240,240,206))
        # Paint the board object to screen
        self.board.paint(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()

    # Handling pygame.QUIT event, and
    # KEYDOWNS. Keydowns is parsed to board.move function
    def eventhandler(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.board.move("LEFT")
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.board.move("RIGTH")
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.board.move("UP")
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.board.move("DOWN")

    # Update function.
    def update(self):
        self.board.update_tiles()

    # Main loop. 60 FPS
    def run(self):

        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            self.eventhandler()
            self.update()
            self.paint()


class Tile:
    def __init__(self,x,y,stage):
        # SETUP tiles x,y and stage. Stage is the number it represents, 2,4,8 etc.
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.stage = stage
        self.colorlist = [(245,240,255),(237,224,200),(242,177,121),(245,149,99),(246,124,95),(246,94,59),(237,207,113),(237,204,97),(237,200,80),(237,197,63),(238,205,94)]

    # Move the tile to new x,y coordinates. Returns False if it moves into a wall.
    def move_tile(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
        if self.x<0 or self.x > 3 or self.y < 0 or self.y > 3:
            self.x -= x
            self.y -=y
            return False
        return True

    # Merge two tiles.
    def merge(self,Tile): 
        if Tile.stage == self.stage:
            self.increasestage()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def increasestage(self):
        self.stage += 1

    # Draw the tile to Board.
    def draw(self,screen,x,y,font):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.colorlist[self.stage-1],(x,y,87,87))

        # draw the numbers on tiles:

        if self.stage <= 2:
            color = (120,110,101)
        else:
            color = (250,248,239)

        text = font.render(str(2**self.stage),2,color)
        screen.blit(text,(x+(87/2 - text.get_width()/2), y + (87/2 -text.get_height()/2)))


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        ## self.tiles keep track of the tiles GUI positions.
        self.tiles = [[0,0,0,0] for i in range(4)]
        self.board = pygame.Rect(50,50,400,400)
        self.color = (186,173,160)
        # tilearray stores the tiles as a list. When self.update_tiles is called
        # the tiles in tile_array gets updated in self.tiles (the tiles GUI position)
        self.tilearray = []
        self.add_tile()
        self.add_tile()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',61)


    #Draw the board background to screen.
    def paint(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,self.board)
        self.drawtiles(screen)

    # Draw tiles to screen. If no tile, draw empty square.
    def drawtiles(self,screen):
        for i,array in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for j,tile in enumerate(array):
                if tile == 0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(204,193,180),(60+i*87+10*i,60+j*87+10*j,87,87))
                else:
                    tile.draw(screen,60+i*87+10*i,60+j*87+10*j,self.font)

    # Returns an arraylist with positions in self.tiles which are empty
    def get_empty_spaces(self):
        empty = []
        for i,array in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for j,tile in enumerate(array):
                if tile==0:
                    empty.append([i,j])

        return empty

    # Add a new tile to the game. Coordinates chosen at random.
    def add_tile(self):
        empty = self.get_empty_spaces()
        chosen = random.choice(empty)

        if random.randrange(1,100) <10:
            stage = 2
        else:
            stage = 1

        t = Tile(chosen[0],chosen[1],stage)

        self.tilearray.append(t)
    # Move all tiles on the board.
    def move(self,key):

        stepstaken = 0

        if key=="LEFT":
            for i, array in enumerate(self.tiles):
                for j, _ in enumerate(array):
                    tile = self.tiles[j][i]
                    if tile!=0:
                        stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,-1,0)
                    self.update_tiles()

        if key =="RIGTH":
            for i,array in enumerate(self.tiles):
                for j,_ in enumerate(array):
                    tile = self.tiles[3-j][3-i]
                    if tile!= 0:
                        stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,1,0)
                    self.update_tiles()

        if key == "UP":
            for i,array in enumerate(self.tiles):
                for j,_ in enumerate(array):
                    tile = self.tiles[i][j]
                    if tile!=0:
                        stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,0,-1)
                    self.update_tiles()

        if key == "DOWN":
            for i, array in enumerate(self.tiles):
                for j,_ in enumerate(array):
                    tile = self.tiles[3-i][3-j]
                    if tile!=0:
                        stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,0,1)
                    self.update_tiles()
        if stepstaken>0:
            self.add_tile()


    # Tiles are stored in self.tilearray. When updating, the tiles from self.tilearray is 
    # stored in the 2d array.

    def move_single_tile(self,tile,vx=0,vy=0):
        steps = 0
        for i in range(0,3):
            if self.position_is_inside_grid(tile.x+vx,tile.y+vy) and self.tile_is_empty(tile.x+vx,tile.y+vy):
                tile.move_tile(vx,vy)
                steps+=1
            else:
                if self.position_is_inside_grid(tile.x+vx,tile.y+vy) and self.tiles[tile.x+vx][tile.y+vy].merge(tile):
                    self.tilearray.remove(tile)
                    steps += 1

        return steps 

    def position_is_inside_grid(self,x,y):
        if x>-1 and x<4 and y>-1 and y<4:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def tile_is_empty(self,x,y):
        if self.tiles[x][y] == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def update_tiles(self):
        self.tiles = [[0,0,0,0] for i in range(4)]
        for tile in self.tilearray:
            self.tiles[tile.x][tile.y] = tile

m = Main()

# TO DO
# Refactor move() to loop functions
#
#
#
```

Answer (score 3):

The code looks good, but the

```
if key=="LEFT":
        for i, array in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for j, _ in enumerate(array):
                tile = self.tiles[j][i]
                if tile!=0:
                    stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,-1,0)
                self.update_tiles()

    if key =="RIGTH":
        for i,array in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for j,_ in enumerate(array):
                tile = self.tiles[3-j][3-i]
                if tile!= 0:
                    stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,1,0)
                self.update_tiles()
```

has some redundant loops. You can move the if statement so the array looping os only written once.

```
for i, array in enumerate(self.tiles):
for j, _ in enumerate(array):
    if key=="LEFT":
        tile = self.tiles[j][i]
        if tile!=0:
            stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,-1,0)
            self.update_tiles()
    if key =="RIGTH":
        tile = self.tiles[3-j][3-i]
        if tile!= 0:
            stepstaken += self.move_single_tile(tile,1,0)
            self.update_tiles()
```

I also recommend to use [Enums](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-python/) for the directions.

When you replace the

```
m = Main()
```

with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   m = Main();
```

This allows you to import this file for example to use the Board class for another project. Otherwise the whole game would run on import.